# Trouble understanding meaning of "driver" in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am having trouble trying to understand what is meant by a MongoDB driver for nodejs. Is *driver* another way to say a module or a library?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day- yes. 
The term comes from os drivers which allow the os to communicate with different hardware.

The mongo driver for node allows node to communicate with an external entity (mongo in this case) using js api inside the node application.